# Switched from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010 and unable to link to boost filesystem now

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, linker-errors, boost-filesystem

I just switched from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010 and one of my projects is now getting a linker error:

LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc90-mt-gd-1_46_1.lib'

I did rebuild boost and I see the vc10 libraries in the lib folder, but I can't figure out why/how it's still referencing the vc90 libraries? I checked the linker properties and I'm pointing to the correct folder (i.e. to the folder of the vc10 libraries). In the input section I'm not specifying the library, so I don't know how it got the reference to the vc90 lib.

Does anybody know what's the solution to this issue?

### Update

The build command that I used to build boost is:

> bjam --build-dir=c:\boost --build-type=complete --with-filesystem --toolset=msvc address-model=64 stage

It automatically resulted in the following output (amongst other things):

> stage\lib\boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_46_1.lib

### Command Line

Linker:

> /OUT:"bin\x64\Debug\NEST2.dll" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\sandbox\boost_1_46_1\bin\x64\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\sandbox\db-5.1.25\build_windows\x64\Release" /DLL "ws2_32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "libdb51.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"tmp\x64\Debug\NEST2.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\dev\app\NEST2\bin\x64\Debug\NEST2.pdb" /ASSEMBLYDEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /PGD:"C:\dev\app\NEST2\bin\x64\Debug\NEST2.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X64 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE

Compiler:

> /I"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\sandbox\boost_1_46_1" /I"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\sandbox\db-5.1.25\build_windows" /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Ot /D "WIN32" /D "_WIN64" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "NEST2_EXPORTS" /D "_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0" /D "__SECURE _SCL=0" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm- /EHsc /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"tmp\x64\Debug\NEST2.pch" /Fa"tmp\x64\Debug\" /Fo"tmp\x64\Debug\" /Fd"tmp\x64\Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /errorReport:queue

### Update 2.0

```
1>------ Build started: Project: NEST2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.Targets(1200,9): warning : The referenced project '{FD045D60-ABAD-4A6C-9794-9BFB085FC3E7}' does not exist.
1>  
1>  Starting pass 1
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:msvcprtd
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:libboost_filesystem-vc90-mt-gd-1_46_1.lib // <--- Here it is
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:libboost_system-vc90-mt-gd-1_46_1.lib // <--- and here!
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:uuid.lib
```

Now if I could only figure out why it's referencing the wrong library!

Comment: Are you using pre-compiled headers? If so, do you have boost headers in your pre-compiled header? Try deleting all intermediate files and rebuilding.

Comment: @Preatorian, hmmm... I'm not using pre-compiled headers.

Comment: When you rebuilt Boost, are you sure you were rebuilding it with VC10?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, I'm pretty sure: I'm looking at the stagin/lib folder now and all of the libraries are labeled as vc100. By the way, here is a pastie with my build output (notice that it's loading the vc100 libraries): http://pastie.org/2174714

Comment: @Lirik: Try defining the preprocessor symbol `BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC` globally for the project. It emits linker messages with the names of the libraries being linked to. Maybe that'll help you trace the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Praetorian ok, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @Preatorian, take a look at [line 8 and 9 of the pastie](http://pastie.org/2174714)... the `DEFAULTLIB:` is `libboost_filesystem-vc90-mt-gd-1_46_1.lib` How does it get set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I updated to Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 the linker issues went away. BUilding boost with the msvc flag or the msvc-10.0 flag resulted in the same output, so that had no effect on the issue.

Additionally, I had to remove the _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL macro because it was causing a mismatch when linking (Linker Error LNK2038).

I'm not sure why it wouldn't link properly until SP1 was installed, so if somebody has an idea, then please post it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your C++ Linker Command Line and make sure it doesn't reference the vc90 libraries. If it is you may have manually added the lib dependency to your 'additional libraries' section.

If you are still unable to fix it, paste both the Compiling and Linking Command Line's here.

Comment: fileoffset, will do as soon as I get back to my work PC. thanks

Comment: I've updated my question with the command line arguments... nothing references VC90. I'll try updating Visual Studio to SP1 and also rebuilding boost with the msvc-10.0 flag on.

Comment: fileoffset, after I installed SP1, the boost linking issues went away. Not sure what was the deal there. On a sidenote: `@fileoffset` seems to be some special thing in StackOverflow and when I type it in the comment section it gets automatically removed (unless I surround it with the single quote-a-ma-thingy.